# How to set datetime through Groovy setter

Tags: datetime, groovy, getter-setter

i have a long value then i convert the Longvalue in datetime format. I am not sure if the conversion is in the right way, but i am able to get in the right format. Now i am struggling to set the converterted datetime in groovy using setter. #formattedDate can be in date format, i do not know how to save in datetime. I get the error conversion String datetime. Please help.

```
def time= 1550670822 / 1000;
            LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(time, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

            String formattedDate = dateTime.format(formatter); 
            trial.setFinishingTime(formattedDate);
```

In my class i have for setFinishingTime.

```
public String getFinishingTime()
    {
        return getPropertyContainer().getString(FINISHING_TIME, "")
    }

    public void setFinishingTime(String finishingTime)
    {
        getPropertyContainer().setString(FINISHING_TIME, finishingTime)
    }
```

This part i am not sure, should it be like this in DateTime format:

```
public DateTime getFinishingTime()
    {
        return getPropertyContainer().getDate(FINISHING_TIME, "")
    }

    public void setFinishingTime(DateTime finishingTime)
    {
        getPropertyContainer().setDate(FINISHING_TIME, finishingTime)
    }
```

If i change this to DateTime how can i store a DateTime of dd:mm:yyyy pattern which i get from the above code. Please help

Comment: ihmo: your question/problem is not clear.

Comment: @daggett: In line **trial.setFinishingTime(formattedDate)** i have used this in string. But i have in String defined. How can i change to DateTime since i have it defined the same in database.

Comment: `DateTime` from which package?

Comment: @daggett : from java.util.Formatter.DateTime.

Comment: there is no such standard class `java.util.Formatter.DateTime`